# Как добавить контент в блок который при клике увеличивается?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется блок `div`, который имеет заголовок. При клике блок увеличивается в размере и в этот момент должен появится контент. Как это можно сделать? После повторного клика, блок возвращается в исходный размер. Код прилагается:

```js
$('.card-warning').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //при втором клике
  if ($('.card-warning').hasClass('w')) {

    $('.card-warning').animate({
      width: 355,
      height: 100
    });

    $('.card-warning').removeClass('w');
  } else {
    //при первом клике
    $('.card-warning').addClass('w');

    $('.card-warning').animate({
      width: 360,
      height: 400
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card text-white card-warning">
  <div class="card-body">
    <blockquote class="card-bodyquote">
      <h5>Медиа / СМИ</h5>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалите Ваш js на изменение размера и используйте css. Добавьте в класс `card-warning` код и ещё пару стилей и измените js. Код ниже. В результате плавно изменится размер и так же появится текст

```js
$('.card-warning').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
}

.card-warning {
    transition: all .4s;
    width: 360px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #9e3f3f !important;
}

.active { 
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
}

.card-body {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .7s;
}

.active .card-body {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card text-white card-warning">
  <div class="card-body">
    <blockquote class="card-bodyquote">
      <h5>Медиа / СМИ</h5>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оформите снипетом

Comment: @doox911 я был с телефона, сейчас оформлю)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! :)